# append values based on unique values in column (pandas)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a column col a that can have values listed multiple times.

For each distinct value in col_a I would like to generate a corresponding random value in col_b.
Like so:

```
col_a  col_b
A     0.25
A     0.25
B     0.12
B     0.12
```

How can I generate col_b?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `random.random()`  for each group:

```
import random
df.groupby('col_a')['col_a'].transform(lambda x: random.random())
Out: 
0    0.394776
1    0.394776
2    0.928343
3    0.928343
Name: col_a, dtype: float64
```

Assign it back:

```
df['col_b'] = df.groupby('col_a')['col_a'].transform(lambda x: random.random())

df
Out: 
  col_a     col_b
0     A  0.012639
1     A  0.012639
2     B  0.839752
3     B  0.839752
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import random


df['col_b'] = 1
df['col_b'] = df.groupby('col_a')['col_b'].transform(lambda _:random.random())
```

Answer (score 0):

Create numbers for the number of unique values in `col_a` and index it with a factorized version of `col_a`

```
u, f = np.unique(df.col_a.values, return_inverse=True)
df.assign(col_b=np.random.rand(u.size)[f])

  col_a     col_b
0     A  0.470264
1     A  0.470264
2     B  0.836461
3     B  0.836461
```

For large data, this is quicker

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.col_a.values)
df.assign(col_b=np.random.rand(u.size)[f])

  col_a     col_b
0     A  0.476353
1     A  0.476353
2     B  0.639068
3     B  0.639068
```